# How to see colorized log file without any escape code?

Tags: linux

I have a colorized log file
How can I see it without any ESC code?

Comment: Does piping your file into `sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mGKF]//g'` work for you? Not all versions of `sed` will handle this. A `perl` command could be worked out that might be more portable.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and tell us how exactly you display the file. Do you want to display the file with colors (instead of visible escape sequences) or do you want to remove the escape sequences that would colorize the output?